# How to set Image instead of text in ListView with Section Header part in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to set Image in Header of ListView Section instead of text. I use ListView with section and in header part I want to set Image so how can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain your problem little bit more ?

Comment: I want to put image in Listview Section Header...in listview with section.insted of Header Text(String).

Comment: are you taking about expandable listview ?

Answer (score 0):

If your're talking about sectioning in listviews like in preferences you can try this tutoeial
http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/
but instead of use my section xml make your own with an imageview